# How to find same-value entries in a dict and select the entry with highest score?

Tags: python

If I have a dict to store an id and an integer score, and another dict to store id and name. Two ids may have the same name, such as 'abc' & 'pqr' both having 'John' as their names.  I want to find entries from id_score_dict with same names and only retain the entry with highest score.

```
id_score_dict = {'abc': 1, 'bcd': 2, 'mnl': 3, 'pqr': 0}

name_dict = {'abc': 'John', 'bcd': 'Mary', 'mnl': 'Cathy', 'pqr': 'John'}

for id, score in id_score_dict.items():
   name = name_dict[id]
   ...
```

For each iteration, the name=name_dict[id] would be updated. How to keep multiple names to compare with each other? For the example above, the id_score_dict after the identification operation would be:

```
id_score_dict = {'abc': 1, 'bcd': 2, 'mnl': 3}
```

'pqr' is removed because it has the same name as 'abc', but with a lower score of '0'. How to solve this problem? I don't know how to identify two ids with same names in the two dicts.

Comment: Please make an attempt and ask a specific question about your attempt.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi for each iteration, the name=name_dict[id] would be updated. How to keep multiple names to compare with each other?

Comment: Please [edit] that into your question.

Comment: `id_score_dict = {key:value for key,value in id_score_dict.items() if value > 0 and key in name_dict}` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new dictionary where the names are the keys. In this dict, store the id and the score as a tuple

```
new_dict = dict()
for p_id, name in name_dict.items():
    # If name is already in new_dict, and
    # the previous score is greater than the current score
    if name in new_dict and new_dict[name][1] > id_score_dict[p_id]:
        # Do nothing
        pass
    else: # Name not in new_dict, or current score is greater
        # Add current item
        new_dict[name] = (p_id, id_score_dict[p_id])
```

At this point, `new_dict` looks like this:

```
{
   'John': ('abc', 1),
   'Mary': ('bcd', 2),
   'Cathy': ('mnl', 3)
}
```

Finally, create a dict out of the `.values()` in `new_dict`

```
id_score_dict_new = dict(new_dict.values())
```

And now we have what we want:

```
{'abc': 1, 'bcd': 2, 'mnl': 3}
```

Comment: Why do I get this error:  new_dict[name] = (p_id, id_score_dict[p_id])
KeyError: 'mml'

Comment: See the edit I made to your question. The input `name_dict` has a key `mml`, but the `id_score_dict`'s key is `mnl` @marlon

Comment: Yes. my typo, sorry about that!

Comment: This seems to be a very smart solution.